# while loop doesnt work fine, c++

Tags: c++, while-loop, do-while

I am actually trying to loop a menu. on the given character my program should respond according to my logic. on press '0' the program should exit, on '1' it should take some new values (which i am taking through a function) and on '2' it should print those values taken. The loop works fine for the first iteration, but when it starts again, it misses a command of input (cin.get) and continues with the flow - doing nothing for this time- and then it gets fine again. I am not sure what is happening.

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
//prototypes

void init_subscriber(Subscriber &s);
void print_subscriber(Subscriber &s);

int main()
{
    char option = ' ';
    Subscriber s1;

while (option != '0')
{
    cout << "Introduce Options:" << endl;
    cout << "(0) exit" << endl << "(1) Add subscriber" << endl << "(2) Print subscribers info" << endl << endl;
    cin.get(option);
    if (option == '1')
    {
        init_subscriber(s1);
    }
    else if (option == '2')
    {
        print_subscriber(s1);
    }
    else if (option == '0')
    {
        option = '0';
    }
}

cout << "we are out of while" << endl;
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about this: The `cin.get` function gives you a single character in the input buffer, but you press *two* keys to enter a single number: The digit *and* the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. That <kbd>Enter</kbd> key will add a newline in the input buffer and it will not be discarded. So the next iteration `cin.get` will read that newline.

The solution? After `cin.get` ask `cin` to [ignore characters until (and including) a newline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Comment: i added "cin.ignore();" after the init_subscribe and print_subscribe funtions, and it seem to work fine. Thanks man!

Comment: Another question:
In the same program I am trying to print an enum obj. I check for the overloaded cout << , it working but it doesnt return the string but and index of the enum objects.


ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Pass& obj)
{
 os << static_cast<std::underlying_type<Pass>::type>(obj);
 return os;
}

Comment: @SarmadAsif If you have a new question, ask a new question.  You can include a link to this question if it helps provide context.